# observeValueForKeyPath crashing app in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm very new to iOS development and trying to wrap my head around why my app is crashing with a message of SIGABRT. I am following along a tutorial ([link](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/)) on how to implement Google Maps SDK and as far as I can tell I have the same code.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var didFindMyLocation = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self

    mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

    }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    }
}

private func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if !didFindMyLocation {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

        didFindMyLocation = true
    }
}
```

The crash happens as I add the last function observeValueForKeyPath and I cannot figure out why. I get the following error message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ': An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: myLocation

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't declared `observeValueForKeyPath(_:ofObject:change:context:)` correctly. Your method expects the wrong argument types for `keyPath`, `ofObject`, and `change`.

The fact that you didn't declare your method `override` is a clue: if you had declared it with the correct types, the compiler would tell you that it also needs to be declared `override`. (It would also tell you that you cannot declare it `private`, because it's `public` in `NSObject`.)

The correct declaration looks like this:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?,
    change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
```

If you just start to type the method name at class scope, Xcode will offer to autocomplete the correct declaration:

[image: Xcode autocomplete]

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it.